# Running FxCop on a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fxcop

Hi I'm implementing an FxCop analysis over our MVC application.  Does anyone have a recommended version and ruleset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use the version built into VS Pro+ with a custom ruleset which is essentially "all rules" minus one or two which are irrelevant to us (e.g., code signing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig.  Does that mean you're using version 1.36 or 10?

Comment: I'm using the version built in to VS 2010 Pro, not a standalone version. Prior to that, I used the version built into VS 2008 Pro. I haven't used a standalone FxCop in years.